# Questions about the site

Tags: support, asking-questions, chat

Is there a chat room for this site? Are you allowed to ask a question of a question, ie., seek further clarification to an answer to your question? Are you allowed to razzle dazzle your posts with colours, photos, etc., using the editor above? Okay that's THREE questions. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Usually it's best to ask questions separately (it's fine; there's no quota :-) ), but I'll go ahead and answer these together since they're short.

> Is there a chat room for this site?

There sure is!  Our main chat room is [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), which you can reach from anywhere on the site by clicking on the blue Stack Exchange logo in the top left corner and then clicking on the "chat" link.  (This is also where you can easily move between the main and meta sites, and access other sites in the network.)  Please come to chat any time you like.  Conversation is pretty free-flowing and might be about anything from posts on the site to current events to people's Shabbat plans to just plain chit-chat.

> Are you allowed to ask a question of a question, ie., seek further clarification to an answer to your question?

Yes.  This is, in fact, what comments are designed for; despite how it may look sometimes, comments *aren't* for extended conversations.  (That's what chat is for.)  It takes 50 reputation to leave a comment in general (this is an anti-spam measure), so you're close, but you can always comment on your own posts and I *think* you can comment on answers to your own questions.  It sounds like that's what you want to do in this case, so please try it and let us know if it worked.  (You can, for example, try to comment on this answer to your meta post.)

If what you're looking for is more of a follow-up that goes beyond the scope of the original question, then you should consider posting a new question rather than a comment. It can be helpful, in that case, to include an explicit link to the first question in the second.

> Are you allowed to razzle dazzle your posts with colours, photos, etc., using the editor above?

Well, I don't think markdown actually supports colors (if you meant text color) and that's probably a good thing, but as you can see from the posting interface, it does support images.  Of course you shouldn't be gratuitous, but that feature is there because sometimes a photo or drawing is really important to understanding something.  So yes, feel free to use images where doing so helps your post, but save LOLCats and the like for other venues. :-)

Comment: Thanks @IsaacMoses.

Comment: I'm feeling a little odd about something. I noticed my answer got a -2 vote or something. People rate my comments/questions? That's a little off-putting. Can you explain the voting business? I don't want to be an annoyance. I want to add value.